# Bash script to create directories with name-checking of contents?

Tags: terminal

How can I make two directories with some file in them, and copy the file between them?

If those files have the same name then an error should be thrown.

Comment: cp -i will prompt you before overwriting

Comment: If you copy _one file_ between the two directories without renaming the file in the process, then the copy will have the same name as the original and there should be an error?  This question is unclear.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

With error notification:

```
mkdir test1 test2
for i in `ls test1/`; do
  if [ ! -e "test2/$i" ] ; then cp "test1/$i" test2/
  else echo "ERROR: test2/$i already exists" >&2
  fi
done
for i in `ls test2/`; do
  if [ ! -e "test1/$i" ] ; then cp "test2/$i" test1/
  else echo "ERROR: test1/$i already exists" >&2
  fi
done
```

Answer (score -1):

Without error notification:

```
mkdir test1 test2
cp --no-clobber test1/* test2/
cp --no-clobber test2/* test1/
```

Comment: Not sure if this addresses the `if those files has same name show error` part of the question.

Comment: Also, there is technically no indication that the OP is using GNU coreutils.

Answer (score -2):

Take the list of files from 2 both directories and save it in 2 files

Directory1_files.txt,Directory2_files.txt.

Let us assume you need to copy the files from Directory1 to Directory2. It should copy only the files from Directory 1 which is not present in Directory 2

```
find First_directory_path -maxdepth 1 -type f  | awk -F "/" '{print $NF}' > Directory1_files.txt

find Second_directory_path -maxdepth 1 -type f  | awk -F "/" '{print $NF}' > Directory2_files.txt


awk 'NR==FNR {a[$1];next}!($1 in a) {print $1}' Directory2_files.txt Directory1_files.txt >Files_need_to_copy_to_directory_2

awk '{print "cp" " " "directory1path/"$1 " " "directory2path"}' Files_need_to_copy_to_directory_2| sh
```

Comment: [Why is looping over find's output bad practice?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/321697/80216)